# how to submit form with multiple form field bearing the same name to database table in flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms, fieldlist

I trying to submit items in a shopping cart to a database table but I can't get a clear understanding or how to implement it using the documentation on `WTFORMS` and other online materials I came across.

I have this forms in my `forms.py`:

```
class CartForm(Form):
    amount = IntegerField('Price')
    item_name = StringField('Product Name')
    quantity = IntegerField('Quantity')
    item_total_amount = IntegerField('Item Total')

class MainForm(FlaskForm):
    total_amount = IntegerField('Total Amount')
    cart_items = FieldList(
    FormField(CartForm),
    min_entries=1,
    max_entries=20)
```

and this is the form in my `template`:
            `checkout.html`

```
    <form name="cart" action="{{ url_for('posts.checkout') }}" method="post" 
    enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <table class="timetable_sub">
                <thead>
                    <tr>


                        <th>Product Name</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Total</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                        {% for item in user_cart %}

                    </tr>
                    <tr name="line_items">

                        <td><input type="text" name="item_name " value="{{item.item_name }}"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" name="quantity " value="{{item.quantity}}"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" name="amount" value="{{item.amount}}"></td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="number" name="item_total_amount "value="item_total_amount 
                        </td>
                       </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tbody></table>

                       <input type="number" name="total_amount" value="total_amount">
                       <input type="submit" value="Register">

            </form>
```

I will appreciate a tutorial link or code base that can help me send this looped for fields to the database table

Comment: The Getting Started docs are pretty straightforward. You need to pass the form object, not your `user_cart` list. WTForms will handle creating your <input> elements for you. Look at the _Quickstart_ and _Creating Forms_ section here. https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html

Comment: @KevinWelch, maybe I did not explain the problem better.
Some of the values are  passed to the forms are from a database table. I know how to render a form perfectly, the main issue is submitting a form that contains a list from a database.

Comment: A list from a database is no different than any other list other than the types inside it, a list in memory is a list in memory. Show the function that renders this template, show some of your code that reads/writes to your database, and give a better description of what exactly your problem is.